# SQL Server 2012 configuration manager not opening in windows 8.1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I run SQLServerManager11.msc in apps to search but nothing happen. Need Help.

It is install and showed in control panel.

Comment: Take a look into the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 2):

On my Win 8.1 system with both SQL Server 2008R2 and SQL Server 2012 installed this is the shortcut that is invoked when I search on SQL Server Configuration Manager in the start screen:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc
```

As you can see it is v10, not 11 like you are typing. Give that a go, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

**To access SQL Server Configuration Manager Using Windows 8**

Because SQL Server Configuration Manager is a snap-in for the Microsoft Management Console program and not a stand-alone program, SQL Server Configuration Manager not does not appear as an application when running Windows 8. To open SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the Search charm, under Apps, type SQLServerManager11.msc (for SQL Server 2012) or SQLServerManager10.msc for (SQL Server 2008), and then press Enter.

Comment: Maybe the search is not as good in plain old Win8? I have no problems bringing it up in the search list if I just start typing `sql server`.

Comment: if you get older,, seach result won't pull anything or will show you very slow as sick